# Examples of processes / problems that cannot be tackled by Turing Machines

Tags: turing-machines, church-turing-thesis

I know that there are problems that cannot be solved by any algorithm, such as the Halting problem.
I also know that some processes cannot be even adequately approximated by any Turing Machine (equivalently, any digital computer), meaning that some property of the process cannot be simulated due to its intrinsic nature. An example of this would be Chaos, and its non-periodicity.

My question is: are there any other interesting processes in nature that really are outside the realm of what Turing Machines / digital computers can tackle? Any other interesting problems (outside from the well-known textbook ones) that Turing Machines cannot solve?

The reason why I ask for this is that I'm teaching to computer science students, and I want to make sure they understand that computers are not all-powerful machines, but there are problems and phenomena that lie *fundamentally* outside the realm of possibilities of any digital computer.
What powerful examples could I use, other than Chaos and the Halting problem, to support my argument?

Thank you!

Comment: This question seems to have infinitely many trivial answers (in fact, you basically answer your own question), so I'm not quite sure you have written down clearly what you'd like to see. Community votes?

Comment: Hi Raphael. I'm not sure how to make my question more precise, because I don't want to restrict the space of answers. So what I'll try to do is to put the question in a discursive way that should encourage some answers rather than others: Let's say that I want to convince a fellow computer scientist that computers are not all-powerful machines, but there are problems and phenomena that - fundamentally- lie outside the realm of possibilities of any digital computer. What powerful examples could I use, other than Chaos and the Halting problem, to support my argument?

Comment: I am not sure chaos is a proper answer, as I suspect it can be
approximated arbitrarily well (and arbitrarily slowly) by a TM. I would expect that one can
study Chaos theory in the context of computable reals. So not even
that would qualify ... unless you want to take into account quantum
fluctuations. But then the real issue is the modelization of quantum
non-determinism (which is far beyond my competence). So the real issue
is possibly to define what you are calling *a problem*.

Comment: Hi Babou. It is true that chaos can be approximated arbitrarily well, but I'll still never get the non-periodicity property and also, no matter how good my approximation is, the main quality of chaos is that the error explodes fast. So let's say that if my problem was something like "find an algorithm that, given an initial condition with a **set** precision, is able to accurately predict the behaviour of my chaotic system arbitrarily far in the future", then I could say that such an algorithm just doesn't exist. No computer can solve this problem, no matter how powerful.

Comment: @GiovanniSirioCarmantini The thing is, no computer scientist with their head screwed on the right way would even argue with your point. Hence, asking for *any* example is both pointless and too broad for this platform. (SE does not take well to discourse, as you put it.)

Comment: I guess you're right. Fact is, I'm teaching to soon-to-be computer scientists and I want to make sure to screw their head in the right way. I thought SE-cs would be the best place to ask for help (maybe this question would be a better fit for a "more discorsive" platform like Quora though). I'd still like to see if I can get any answer at all, otherwise I'll just delete the question if it is not a good fit for the community.

Comment: There is some possibly related stuff I can point to along those lines, regarding the links between physics and the Church-Turing thesis. Some can be found on the SE physics site ... just look for Turing as a keyword there.  But I fear it may be hard to follow for students, especially since not so many are proficient on both physical and computational concepts. Regarding Math, the whole theory was developed in response to Hilbert's questionning of the limitation of the foundations of mathematics (Entscheidungsproblem) -cc @Raphael

Comment: @babou: thanks, I'll go and check it out. Well I don't really need to explain to them in detail, the important thing is that they have in the back on their minds that "nature's imagination is so much greater than man's" as Feynman put it, and that digital computers are actually limited in what they can do.

Comment: Nature's imagination may be greater than man's, but I do not think I
would follow you in asserting too easily that it follows that
`computers are actually limited in what they can do`, implicitly
because computers are man made. My own suspicion, which I cannot prove
of course, is rather that the limitations of computation are due to
fundamental characteristics of the universe, such as discreteness.
Democritus is not dead yet.

Comment: Well, a part of the question is rather pointless (totally obscure examples of uncomputable problems wouldn't really help anyone reading this in the future). But there are interesting ones (in the sense that they appear naturally) that while are in some book, are perhaps not well known.

Comment: Well, I don't want to **assert** that there is more out there than just digital computation. But surely I want to make room in their minds for the possibility that the nature of the universe may be very different from that of our computers. The "computable universe" idea tends to be taken for granted (or at least, I didn't doubt it when I was the age of my students) probably because computers are an incredibly powerful tool. But it should not, and as computer *scientists* they have to be well aware that we don't have this kind of certainty. And cases like Chaos help illustrate the point.

Comment: @GiovanniSirioCarmantini: and I think you serious misunderstand what [chaos theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) is about: "Chaos: When the present determines the future, but the approximate present does not approximately determine the future." It's all about the effect of perturbations, rather than an impossibility of performing the computation.

Comment: I do understand that we can approximate chaos. In fact it is very easy to find simulators for chaotic systems. But computers are not able for example to reproduce the non-periodicity of chaos. Approximate? Sure. But if we had the possibility to start a simulation on the fanciest computer, and then at the same time a chaotic system, the simulated chaotic system will enter an orbit in finite time, while the real one will not. Of course I'm aware that you can theoretically get as long as a non-repeating orbit you need, but still you are bound. Assuming there is *real* Chaos in the physical world

Comment: What's the "fanciest computer"? This seems to have turned into a debate about [digital physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics) as I feared it was going to...

Comment: @RespawnedFluff "fanciest computer" as in any digital computer with a finite number of state (no matter how big). Well, I really don't want to turn this into a debate about digital physics, as I have to admit, that would be way bigger than me. Not nearly knowledgeable enough to give any  meaningful contribution. But I see that this conclusion was somehow implied in my original question.

Comment: seems like halfway decent question to me, maybe not asked in a perfect way. there seem to be many undecidable problems that seem to touch on more applied areas... some of this is connected to physics theory....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll address as answer only part of the question (see my comments for why not all of it). The interesting phylosophical part of the question is basically asking if the Church-Turing thesis (CTT) describes all that happens in the universe. This is much more a physics question than it really is a CS question. CTT has been extended to the [Church–Turing–Deutsch principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing%E2%80%93Deutsch_principle) to account for quatum computers; it basically states that a quantum computer can simulate any physical process in the universe.

So what about continuous processes that we normally model over $\mathbb{R}$? Well, there are two aspects of this:

- [Models of computation with infinite-precision real-numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_computation) have been devised. Whether you think such a model is the "right" one for physical processes, depends on physics and...
- There are tough issues like the [Bekenstein bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound), which limit the amount of information that can exist in a finite region of space as we currently understand it. For details on this latter issue, it's much better to ask on our physics sister site.

A bit more info with pointer to additional readings is found at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54820/physics-and-church-turing-thesis

Comment: I would upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation to do so. But thank you!

Comment: The issue with chaotic systems is one of the effect of perturbations on approximate solutions. An one does not have to get to differential equations to illustrate that. Even a banal system of linear equations has a notion of [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number), which is an intrinsic measure of the instability of the problem's solution to perturbations in input.

Comment: Another thing worth saying about chaos theory is that formal proofs of chaotic behavior are often very difficult and require a computer's assistance; this type of proof, relying on [interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) should not be confused with simulations of dynamic systems using approximate representations. For example, the proof of the long-standing conjecture on the existence of a Lorenz strange attractor was done [precisely this way](https://books.google.com/books?id=8MXHEGxfAvAC&pg=PA219) by Tucker.

Answer (score -1):

it is known some problems in theoretical physics are undecidable. have not found a nice simple list/ survey. see eg these two refs.

- [Classical problem becomes undecidable in a quantum setting](http://phys.org/news/2012-07-classical-problem-undecidable-quantum.html) / physorg
- [Undecidability and intractability in theoretical physics](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/academic/undecidability-intractability-theoretical-physics.pdf) / Wolfram. the basic idea here is that CAs, cellular automata nearly reflect physical processes and many aspects of CA behavior are undecidable. this was not realized early on in the study CAs when this paper was written.
- another ref [Church’s thesis meets the N-body problem](http://research.cs.queensu.ca/home/akl/cisc879/papers/PAPERS_FROM_APPLIED_MATHEMATICS_AND_COMPUTATION/Special_Issue_on_Hypercomputation/smith%5B1%5D.pdf) / Smith asserts (with many refs) that physics is "unsimulable" by computers.